# How to move options from one select to another in aurelia?

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I am trying to move **selected options** in select1 to select2 on the `click` of a button. This is my HTML code:

```
<p>
<select id="select1" size="10" style="width: 25%" multiple>
    <option value="purple">Purple</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="grey">Grey</option>
</select>
</p>

<button type="button" click.delegate="trig()">Add</button>

<p>
<select id="select2" size="10" style="width: 25%" multiple>
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

And here is my JS code Containing the button

```
export class App {
  constructor() {
  }

  trig() {

  }
}
```

What would I have to put in `trig()` so that on click the button will move selected items to another list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through the `selectedColors1` and get the `index` of each selected item. Then push them to `color2` array and remove them from the `colors` array one by one.

**Demo**: [**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/oj84xj0opz)

```
export class App {
  colors1 = [
    { id: "purple", name: "Purple" },
    { id: "black", name: "Black" },
    { id: "orange", name: "Orange" }
  ];

  colors2 = [
    { id: "white", name: "White" },
    { id: "red", name: "Red" },
    { id: "blue", name: "Blue" }
  ];

  selectedColors1 = [];
  selectedColors2 = [];

  add() {
    this.selectedColors1.forEach(selected => {
      // get the index of selected item
      const index = this.colors1.findIndex(c => c.id === selected);
      this.colors2.push(this.colors1[index]); // add the object to colors2
      this.colors1.splice(index, 1); // remove from colors1
    });
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select multiple value.bind="selectedColors1">
  <option repeat.for="color of colors1" model.bind="color.id">
    ${color.name}
  </option>
</select>

<button type="button" click.delegate="add()">Add</button> <br />

<select multiple value.bind="selectedColors2">
  <option repeat.for="color of colors2" model.bind="color.id">
    ${color.name}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have added  `add`  button as per your use case.
Please refer below link and I have updated the solution. I guess your are looking for somewhat same.

[Sample StackBlitz](https://codesandbox.io/s/6lznw769vz)

If you required more help, please comment on this.

Comment: It looks like you are hitting what I need, but I am trying to make it work on the click of a button. Anyway you know how to do that? Thanks again

Comment: Also, I would like the color to move over to the other list and leave the original list, I also want to be able to put multiple colors over to the other list

Comment: I have updated the solution. Please refer my answer, I have updated it.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but include the necessary parts of your answer in the answer here. Links can become invalid which would make the answer as it stands useless.